# can't install y-ppa-manager via terminal

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

After running the following code

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

couldn't access to `y-ppa-manager`, the program doesn't exist on my system.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure it was indeed installed? What do you see when you type `y-ppa-manager` in the terminal?

Comment: if you type `sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager`, it will ask you to install it if it's not already and if it's installed it will simply tell you this package is already installed. :)

Comment: I am not really sure whether it was installed or not but after running the code it seemed like fetching the repositories or whatever it is called.But when I search for y-ppa manager on my unity dash it does not show up. Isn't there any way to download for Ubuntu 14.04lts. And if there is than please teach me step by step. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy y-ppa-manager`say?

Comment: I don't know . What do I do to fix it. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install using deb packages that you can download using browser.
double click to install  it. if it says unmet dependency then you find it on same page of this link.
[Download link for Y-PPA MAnager](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.04/getdeb-apps-i386/y-ppa-manager_0.0.9.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb.html)

Comment: It says ,Download y-ppa-manager_0.0.9.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
from the GetDeb Apps repository.Whereas I'm using Ubuntu14.04. And I can't figure out how to download or find deb packages. Please show me thoroughly since I'm a newbie. Thanks.

Comment: direct link: http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/www.getdeb.net/getdeb/ubuntu/pool/apps/y/y-ppa-manager/y-ppa-manager_0.0.9.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb

Comment: Thank you very much,Mr. Torvalds you've been thorough in explaining.

Comment: Mr.Torvalds, now that I've successfully installed y-ppa-manager and enabled all that was in advanced y-ppa-manager like;Try to import all GPG keys;Try to fix all GPG BADSIG errors;and after all that is done, I tried to update via terminal but it says:'E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/" What do I do? Help is in need!

Comment: @user279506 try this solution: http://askubuntu.com/a/15436/294611

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Thanks for your time and help me fixing my system.